# Can't uses keyboard in setup

Tags: keyboard, lg

I'm trying to setup a LG LS665 and I can't put my internet password in or anything that requires text entry. I think i might have deleted the default lg keyboard. Anything i can do to fix it? Is it possible to install an apk from my pc without any interaction from my phone?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a Google account set up, and the device connected to the Internet, you can simply visit the *Google Play Store* using a browser on your PC, log in, find a keyboard app, and click the button to install it on your device (it will then be pushed).

As I somehow doubt that the requirements for that are met (or you wouldn't ask about setup), a second variant would be to download the `.apk` file of a keyboard app and use e.g. `adb install` to get it installed. Problem: for this you need to have [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging) enabled on the device. Not sure if you can achieve that.

Last resort would be to "flash" a keyboard app via a special `update.zip` in recovery. But that would require a custom recovery, and the `update.zip` must be created (there are posts on that here on this site as well). Some custom recoveries also offer ADB access (e.g. [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp) has that built-in), so you could try the `adb install` approach with them. However, I cannot tell if there is any (or which) custom recovery available for your device.

Very last resort: flash the entire firmware again – the keyboard app should be part of it.